# Setting ALT as ID

Tags: jquery, area, imagemap

```
$('area').qtip({
    content: $('#whatever-this-area-tags-alt-is'),
    position: {
        my: 'top left',    
        at: 'middle'
    },
    show: { delay: 0 },
    hide: { delay: 200 }
});
```

I'd like to set content ID to whatever the current `area`'s alt is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through and use `this` to refer to the current `<area>` inside the loop, like this:

```
$('area').each(function() {
  $(this).qtip({
    content: $("#" + $(this).attr("alt")),
    position: {
        my: 'top left',    
        at: 'middle'
    },
    show: { delay: 0 },
    hide: { delay: 200 }
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't want to show 'alt' but an element that has the ID same as the alt.